# Laravel checking data with API through API

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5.8

I have some data that compressed with gzip in an application from here:
`app.myaddress.com/data/api/1`.

The data contains several parameters in JSON format like follows:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "data": "abcabcabcabcabc" //this is the compressed data
}
```

I need to check the compressed `data` with another 3rd party service, we can just say the address like follows: `app2.myaddress.com/check_data/abcabc` by API request, but it's needed a header authentication:

```
{
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "api-key": 123456
}
```

`app2.myaddress.com` will return data JSON format like follows:

```
{
    "name": "hello",
    "address": "australia"
}
```

What I need to do is just checking a data by accessing URL like:
`app.myaddress.com/data/api/checked/1`
then the controller will process the data include checking through `app2.myaddress.com` and return the value into `app.myaddress.com`

Comment: Welcome to SO.  We're here bcs we want to help, but SO is not a code-writing service.  Show use what you've tried.  Are you planning to do this in Laravel, or Javascript?  If you don't have any code yet, you'll need to do some research, make a start, and ask here with details if it isn't working.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can use `cURL` or `Guzzle` to access both URL inside your function.
here the documentation of Guzzle 
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by [@rafitio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6305480/rafitio):

You can use cURL or Guzzle to access both URL inside your function. Here is the documentation of Guzzle: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html